# Discord "messageCreate" and "InteractionCreate" events does not work

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was trying to do a simple command using the clasic message event (now `messageCreate` event), so I programed a small code to test if the event is working righfully:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { Client, Intents, Message, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js');
const { token, prefix } = require('./config.json')


const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.username} Se Ha Conectado Correctamente`)
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    console.log('Un Mensaje! :D');
    console.log(message);
})
client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    console.log(interaction);
})

client.login(token);
```

But when I send the messages at the guild where I am testing the bot, he can't detect them for some reason.

as extra data, the `console.log` of the ready event works perfectly.

> Fixes testings

Maybe permissions? It already have administrator but I moved the role to the top for testing, nothing happened.

Maybe add the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent on the client? I also tried this one but the bot still can't detect the messages

```
Discord.js version: v13.3.1
Node.js version: v17.0.1
```

Comment: which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Using v13.3.1, I forgotten write it on the post, I edited the post to add it ;)

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, except for some little things like the double require and the listeners placed outside of the ready callback, but it should log messages. I built a bot using v12 of discordjs so i don't know exactly how node works with v13, but, i saw on some other quesion that some version of node doesn't work as expected with discordjs. Maybe you can try to use another version of node and test it

Comment: You need to get the right intents for your bot. Right now you only have the guild intent however to receive messages you also need the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent. See [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) for more intents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Worthly Alpaca has mentioned in the comments, it is required to use the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent in order to be able to receive the messages. Your client will now look like:

```js
const client = new Client({intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]});
```

Please note that you now have to enable the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent on the page of your Discord application.

Comment: It's message **content** intent (messageCreate events still emit but content is an empty string if the intent isn't enabled). Also, the message content intent is only needed if the bot is verified, I believe.

Comment: Thank you man, this intents thing is new for me bc the last time I programmed a bot was on the v11 of discord with the old API page, so thanks you two Luuk and Worthly Apaca so much!